# Video Viewer Count Missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, asset-library

I added the star rating feature to my asset library and now I can see how many people have rated a video in the library, but not how many have viewed it. How do I get the viewer count back?

Answer (score 0):

Library Settings-> Advanced Settings -> Reindex Library. Once the next crawl reindexed the library, the view counts came back.